# C compiler error

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char* number1[100] = {argv[1]};
    char* a;
    char* separate = "/ \n";
    int alpha, beta, gamma, delta;
    int i;
    a = strtok(number1, separate);
    printf("%s",a); 
}
```

When I compile it, it keeps giving me a warning saying that: **"'char * ' differs in level of indirection from 'int'"** but all I am using so far are char*.

The full error message is as follows:

```
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:9:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

(line 9: `a = strtok(number1, separate);`)

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: why are you not using the `int`s you have declared? or Otherwise?

Comment: On which line do you get the warning?

Comment: i need to use them later on when i get my current problem to work. my apologies if it confused you. and the warning appeared on line 9

Comment: It should be ``char* number1 = argv[1];`` on line 4.

Comment: tried it. same warning still appears

Comment: You also probably ought to make sure `argv[1]` even exists before you blindly use it to initialize something else...

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string.h>` - you also forgot to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @twalberg: `argv[1]` has to exist; even if the environment can't determine the name of the program, it must set `argv[0]` to an empty string, so `argc >= 1`, and `argv[argc] == 0`, so `argv[1]` might be a null pointer, but it exists.  Having said that, invoking `strtok()` with a null pointer for the first argument before invoking it with a non-null first argument is likely to be undefined behaviour.  Definitely treading on thin ice when the code uses `argv[1]` (via `number1` -- incorrectly, since the first argument to  `strtok()` should be a `char *` and not a `char **`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, although not true for `argv[2]` and above... So it's not something I like to make an assumption out of, lest it lead me astray...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not include `string.h`, so the `strtok` function is not declared. In old versions of the C language it is allowed to use a function that is not declared (though gcc should produce a(n additional) warning about this - at least with `-Wall`), in which case the return type of the function is assumed to be `int`. So the compiler thinks that `strtok` returns an int and consequently warns you that you're trying to assign that int to a pointer.

To fix this, simply add the missing include.

Once you have fixed this, the compiler will complain `number1` has the wrong type to be used with `strtok` (it's an array of pointers rather than a pointer), but that's a different issue.

Comment: thank you! i knew i was missing something!

Comment: @user3633372: If your compiler wasn't telling you about an undeclared function `strtok()`, you need to learn how to make it tell you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
char number1[100];
strcpy(number1,argv[1]);
```

Also, with no string.h and no warnings, it assumes strtok() is a nominal function returning an int, thus the typing mismatch.

Comment: same warning still appears. i tried both methods

Comment: @Jim Your first option is definitely invalid.