# Strtok returning garbage

Tags: c, linux, parsing, strtok, strcmp

I'm trying to parse a file with strtok and strcmp. I'm new to Eclipse developing on Linux and having some issues with getting everything to work. The only thing i'm linking against is -lm so I'm not sure if this is a linking issue of some type or what.

1. It crashes on the first strcmp after strtok.
2. strtok pointer returned cannot be inspected by the debugger and is not NULL. Trying to inspect the token says 'Error: Cannot access memory address'.
3. strtok properly modifies the fileBuffer location with the appropriate '\0' character. The return pointer is garbage for some reason.
4. This is the first and only section of my code I use strtok.
5. I'm 100% sure the file loaded correctly and the appropriate string is in fileBuffer with no issues through using the Eclipse debugger.

```c
char fileBuffer[2048];

for(i=0;i < 7;i++)
{
    sprintf(filepath,"%s/Room%d.txt",directory,i);

    FILE* file = fopen(filepath,"r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Expected file @ %s/Room%d.txt does not exist. Cannot complete loading game.",directory,i);
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(file);
    assert((size + 1) < sizeof(fileBuffer));

    fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);
    fread(fileBuffer,sizeof(char),size,file);
    fclose(file);
    fileBuffer[size]='\0';

    const char* delimiters = ":\n";
    //!!!! This returns garbage that crashes the program when
    //submitted to strcmp for comparisons.
    const char* t = strtok(fileBuffer,delimiters);

    while(t != NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(t,"ROOM NAME") == 0)
        {
            t = strtok(NULL,delimiters);
            RoomIndex[i] = NameToIndex(t + 1);
        }
        else if(strcmp(t,"ROOM TYPE") == 0)
        {
            t = strtok(NULL,delimiters);
            for(j = 0; j < 3;j++)
            {
                if(strcmp(t + 1,RoomType[j]) == 0)
                {
                    rooms[i].RoomType = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        t = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strtok()` is a terrible function. If you can help it (you can), then don't use it.

Comment: eh it is an assignment where I'm supposed to use only the basic c libraries to load and unload data. I typically use C++, I was trying to avoid writing my own parsing functions, but it is looking like I might have to as I can't understand the error. It appears to just be broken as far as I can tell.

Comment: I suspect the issue is `const char* t` as the reuse of `t` within the loop will be an attempted modification and should crash. Try it as `char* t`

Comment: Good point, OP is trying to get one extra char, should be `size - 1` (although as long as `size < 2048` he is in the clear)

Comment: No. I created the files myself and they aren't even 256 characters. I just made them really big so I wouldn't need to pay close attention to the size of the buffers. The fileBuffer[size]='\0' is to make sure the imported file as a '\0' character at the end so I can make sure it is a null terminated string for processing. I wasn't 100% sure if loading a text file guaranteed a '\0' character at the end of the text.

Comment: My pitiful excuse for a crystal ball tells me you didn't pull in `<string.h>` to this source file when compiling it. If that is the case, and adding it fixes the problem, *and* you're the least bit interested in knowing *why*, comment back.

Comment: @Barmar You're very right, I remove immediately this stupid comment.

Comment: Whoz you are a genius. I didn't think I needed that : / Lay it on me big man, why am I a dumb dumb. I'm guessing there is global state there related to strtok but that would make me wonder why on earth it compiles without it.

Comment: @jdarthenay Don't feel bad, I asked a similar question earlier, then noticed the assert. :)

Comment: @user2927848 Nothing to do with global state, just the correct declarations of the arguments and return value.

Comment: A good compiler will warn you when you call functions that haven't been properly declared.

Comment: @Barmar OP using assert but not compiling with `-Wall`, that's so evil...

Comment: @WhozCraig - now I'm interested. How the heck would it even compile without it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin C gives default declarations for functions.

Comment: Because the compiler believed strtok was `int strtok(int, int)`.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with compiling raw C. Learning experience.

Comment: @Barmar, Ah, yes... But, you would suspect a train of warnings spewing like spaghetti across the terminal in that case. Now we will have to see what it would default to... `:)`

Comment: @user2927848 Barmar is correct (as usual). By not providing a proper prototype from the header the compiler is implicitly declaring the function as taking an arbitrary number of arguments and `int` for the return type: `int strtok()`. My same pitiful crystal ball tells me you're compiling on a 64bit platform with 32bit native `int`. Thus the compiler is generating code that only reaps 32bits of the 64bit real return value, converts it to a pointer, and stuffs it in `t`. Cranking up your warning levels to pedantic levels would flag all sorts of warnings surrounding this issue in your code.

Comment: And in case you're wondering, the hint to me that was the case was your well-formed analysis that indeed *something* was returned from `strtok` that was not NULL, but did not appear to be an address within your buffer, and was not dereferencable by the debugger for analysis.

Comment: Very much appreciated man.

Comment: Lesson learned: Take your compiler's warnings for serious.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23636564/694576 if not a duplicate.

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  When asking questions of the `why does my code not work?` variety, post code that cleanly compiles, (including the `#include` statements) also post the actual input, the actual output, and the expected output.